# Send email via Ruby code on Heroku

Tags: ruby, email, heroku, sinatra

I'm having problems sending email via my Ruby code. You can see my [full code on GitHub](https://github.com/Integralist/Passage).

UPDATE: the below code has been amended to reflect suggestions from @Gaurish

UPDATE2: looks like gmail refused the login attempt - I received an email from them to warn me some unknown application tried to access my account but they disabled it

The specific class is here:

```
require 'net/smtp'

=begin
    http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Net/SMTP/start/class
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

    I added the following config vars to Heroku
    heroku config:add GM_USR=xxxx
    heroku config:add GM_PSW=xxxx
=end

class Email
    def initialize (to, from, subject, body)
            @to = to
            @from = from
            @subject = subject
            @body = body
            @message = <<MESSAGE_CONTENT
                From: User <#{@from}>
                To: Integralist <#{@to}>
                MIME-Version: 1.0
                Content-type: text/html
                Subject: #{@subject}
                #{@body}
MESSAGE_CONTENT

            @smtp = Net::SMTP.new('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        end

        def send_email
            @smtp.enable_starttls
            @smtp.start('furious-wind-9309.herokuapp.com', ENV['GM_USR'], ENV['GM_PSW'], :login) do |smtp|
            @smtp.send_message(@message, @from, @to)
        end
    end
end
```

I'm calling it like so:

```
email = Email.new('myemail@gmail.com', params[:email], 'test subject', params[:message]);
email.send_mail
```

But when I execute the code I get the error displayed on screen: `535-5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at`

I checked the logs and I get...

```
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 heroku[router]: POST furious-wind-9309.herokuapp.com/contact dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=628ms status=500 bytes=2060
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1334:in `block in call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1416:in `synchronize'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1334:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:1060:in `call'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:1060:in `block in spawn_threadpool'
2012-06-13T08:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 82.69.39.185 - - [13/Jun/2012 08:01:08] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 500 2060 0.6254
```

I know people will likely suggest ActionMailer or Pony, but I'd rather not use those or have those suggested to me please. I'd instead like a solution that helps fix the above code instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Update 1]**

If gmail doesn't work for you, you can use [SendGrid Addon](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid) which gives you upto 200emails per day at no charge.

Here is a sample(taken from [docs](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/ruby-email-example-using-smtp/)) on how to use their STMP API with [mail gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mail)

```
require 'mail'
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, { :address   => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
                           :port      => 587,
                           :domain    => "yourdomain.com",
                           :user_name => "yourusername@domain.com",
                           :password  => "yourPassword",
                           :authentication => 'plain',
                           :enable_starttls_auto => true }
end

mail = Mail.deliver do
  to 'yourRecipient@domain.com'
  from 'Your Name <name@domain.com>'
  subject 'This is the subject of your email'
  text_part do
    body 'Hello world in text'
  end
  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body '<b>Hello world in HTML</b>'
  end
end
```

Using Sendgrid is much better solution because you also get access Advanced reporting & analyticss which are not available with gmail. Also, there is no restriction on "from" addresses in sendgrid.

---

With Heroko, you can't send emails directly from `localhost` because [Heroku does not provide an outgoing mail service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp).

so you will have to consider an *external* smtp server for sending your emails. popular ones are [Gmail](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/11/9/tech_sending_email_with_gmail/) & [Sendgrid](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid)

this is just one trade-off of using a cloud computing platform like heroku.

With Gmail, try doing something like this:

```
require 'net/smtp'

    msg = "your message goes here"
    smtp = Net::SMTP.new 'smtp.gmail.com', 587
    smtp.enable_starttls
    smtp.start(YourDomain, YourAccountName, YourPassword, :login) do
      smtp.send_message(msg, FromAddress, ToAddress)
    end
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this tomorrow. But what is the YourDomain parameter going to be if I've not got one setup yet? For example I'm accessing the site via a Heroku provided URL (for the moment) so would I specify that in full: http://appname.heroku.com ?

Comment: Yes for more, please consult the [API docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Net/SMTP/start/class)

Comment: this doesn't work I'm afraid. I've updated my question to reflect the new code I'm using. Maybe you can advise on where I might be going wrong. Thanks

Comment: you can use sendgrid as I updated my answer on how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```
@email = Email.new('mark.mcdx@gmail.com', params[:email], 'test subject', params[:message])
@email.send_email
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load up SendGrid as an add-on and it works right out of the box.  Plus you get a whole suite of analytics for troubleshooting bounces, deliveries, etc...